# Dropdownbox.selectedvalue passing to sql comment

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dropdownbox

```
string ddorder = DropDownList2.SelectedValue; // column
string ddtype = DropDownList3.SelectedValue; //asc or desc
String str1 = "Select * from table1 order by("+ddorder+"  "+ddtype+")";
```

//there is an error beacuse of ddtype, what am I doing wrong?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1, DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
GridView2.DataSource = ds1;
GridView2.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) code is inside this

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ıt shows here but because of +ddtype+ in string str1.

Comment: update the question with error description..

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't need to use `(` and `)` in order by clause. [It's syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) doesn't have any usage for `(` or `)`.

For example;

```
order by id desc
```

will work but

```
order by (id desc)
```

won't work.

By the way, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Also you don't need `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` part for a SELECT statement. It is unnecessary since it's *just* execute your select query. It doesn't do or return something.

A few things more;

- Change your `table1` to something meaningful.
- Don't use `SELECT *`. [It's quite bad](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis in the "order by" clause:

```
String str1 = "Select * from table1 order by "+ddorder+" "+ddtype;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This would solve his problem, read the error : An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dynamic Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

Change Here:

```
string ddorder = DropDownList2.SelectedValue; // column
string ddtype = DropDownList3.SelectedValue; //asc or desc
String str1 = "exec(Select * from table1 order by "+ddorder+"  "+ddtype+")";
```

and

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1);
GridView2.DataSource = ds1;
GridView2.DataBind();
con.Close();
```